# Torsion-charged Levi-Civita connection

Tags: differential-geometry

While I study (differential) geometry, the most concept-relevant topic I stumbled upon takes the name of Levi-Civita and their connection. This definition allows transporting vectors along curves in manifolds compatible with its metric. An important requirement for such a concept is its $\textbf{torsion-free}$ property. What happens for the relaxed case of a free-charged connection?

Comment: A manifold can have many connections; the point of the LC connection is that starting with only a metric there is a *unique* connection satisfying the requirements. Without the torsion-free requirement, you lose uniqueness.

Comment: I thank you for the explanation.